# PHP regex partially failing in the last check

Tags: php, regex

I want to filter user input from the form, all the variables are set up correctly.
Regex is failing only on the last if, where I compare additional product property, size, weight or dimensions. And only size parameter is filtered correctly, other ones are just ignored because I can put anything to the weight and dimensions and regex will accept it. 
For example:

```
Test input:
Size: aaaa // Does not let through
Weight: aaaa // Lets through
Dimensions: aaaa // Lets through
```

There is OR in code in last if, because only one parameter is mandatory for submission.

Here is the code responsible for regex:

```
if(!empty($UI->sku) && !empty($UI->name) && !empty($UI->price)) {
    if(!empty($UI->size) || !empty($UI->weight) || !empty($UI->dimensions)) {
        if(preg_match("/^\d+$/" , $UI->sku)) { // Checking if sku is int
            if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/" , $UI->name)) { // Checking if name consists only of numbers and letters
                if(preg_match("/^(?=.)([+-]?([0-9]*)(\.([0-9]+))?)$/" , $UI->price)) { // Checking if price is float or int
                    if(preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/" , $UI->size) || preg_match("/^(?=.)([+-]?([0-9]*)(\.([0-9]+))?)$/" , $UI->weight) || preg_match("/^[0-9]+x[0-9]+x[0-9]+$/" , $UI->dimensions)) {
                        //Checking additional product parameters for valid format
                        $UI->addToDatabase();
                    } else {
                        echo "Check your product's additional property!";
                        exit;
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "Check your product's price!";
                    exit;
                }
            } else {
                echo "Check your product's name!";
                exit;
            }

        } else {
            echo "Check your product's SKU!";
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        echo "Please add additional parameter to your product!";
        exit;
    }
} else{
    echo "Please, include all the product's parameters!";
}
```

Comment: You may find the code easier to read if you reorganised it to be an if with the message and exit rather than such a nested bunch of statements.  So `if(empty($UI->sku) || empty($UI->name) || empty($UI->price)) { echo "Please, include all the product's parameters!"; exit;}`

Comment: What have you tried to debug this code? Where **exactly** does it go wrong, and what have you tried to resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

First, you check if one of three object properties have a "truthy" value with:

```
if(!empty($UI->size) || !empty($UI->weight) || !empty($UI->dimensions)) {
```

Then you check if one of three object properties pass your validation rules with:

```
if (preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/" , $UI->size)
    || preg_match("/^(?=.)([+-]?([0-9]*)(\.([0-9]+))?)$/" , $UI->weight)
    || preg_match("/^[0-9]+x[0-9]+x[0-9]+$/" , $UI->dimensions)
) {
```

So if $UI->dimensions was the lone "additional" value submitted, then I would expect that you would be generating **Warning: Undefined property** on `$UI->weight` and `$UI->dimensions`.

If this were my project, I would employ NigelRen's guidance and reconstruct the nested conditions for improved readability and accuracy.  I make a habit of writing all false/failure outcomes early and true/successful outcomes later.

Untested Code:

```
if (!isset($UI->sku, $UI->name, $UI->price)) {  // if any of the required properties are not declared or are null
    exit("Please include all the product's parameters.");
}
if (!ctype_digit((string)$UI->sku)) {  // if sku not fully comprised of digits
    exit("Please ensure that your product's SKU only contains digits.");
}
if (!preg_match("/^[a-z\d ]+$/i", $UI->name)) { // if name not fully comprised of alphanumeric and space characters
    exit("Please ensure that your product's name contains only alphanumeric characters and spaces.");
}
if (!preg_match("/^[+-]?\d*\.?\d+$/", $UI->price)) { // if price is not a float or int (optional sign before optional digits before optional dot before required digit(s))
    echo "Please ensure that your product's price is a numeric value.";
}
if (!isset($UI->size) && !isset($UI->weight) && !isset($UI->dimensions)) {  // if no additional parameters have been submitted
    exit("Please add additional size/weight/dimensions parameter to your product.");
}
if (isset($UI->size) && !ctype_digit((string)$UI->size)) {  // if size exists and is not fully comprised of digits
    exit("Please ensure that your product's size only contains digits.");
}
if (isset($UI->weight) && !preg_match("/^+?\d*\.?\d+$/", $UI->weight)) {  // if weight exists and is not numeric (no negative weight allowed)
    exit("Please ensure that your product's weight is a non-negative numeric value.");
}
if (isset($UI->dimensions) && !preg_match("/^\d+x\d+x\d+$/", $UI->dimensions)) { // if dimensions exists and doesn't match the required format
    exit("Please ensure that your dimension value contains three numbers separated by the letter x.");
}
$UI->addToDatabase();
```